# How to remove all previous Fragments from back stack leaving the current fragment visible

Tags: android, android-fragments

Is there any way to remove all the previous fragments in the back stack leaving only the visible one on the stack?

Comment: But in the suggested solution on that link is to implement popBackStack method, that removes the current fragment, and I want to keep it.